# Selenium error in python 3 || lib\subprocess.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, error-handling

I'm using a simple code in python3.4.4

```
import time
# importing webdriver from selenium
from selenium import webdriver
 
# Here Chrome  will be used
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
 
# URL of website
url = "https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/"
 
# Opening the website
driver.get(url)
 
# getting the button by class name
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("slide-out-btn")
 
# clicking on the button
button.click()
```

I was show this error :

```
File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Python3\lib\subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1114, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Projects\ai\button_clicker.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Comment: Hello and welcome, you can probably format you question better. All the `#` in your question body are causing these very big title messages, it's actually making it hard to follow the code. You can wrap the contents of your code in a code block - that's a more appropriate way to share `code`